# e4 RCP: programmatically open part in new window

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I would like to programmatically open an MPart in a new MWindow.
Similar to as if I would create the part in a partstack somewhere in the existing window and then manually drag it away with the mouse.

So, one way would be to create a non-rendered window which contains this part. And once it should be shown, we can set it to being rendered. But: once we close this window, we cannot bring it back?!

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me:

- Define an empty window in the e4xmi which is set to not be rendered
- Once we want to display the part, we create it (if it is not open already) and add it to the window

```java
    MUIElement window = modelService.find(myWindowId, app);
    MPart part = (MPart) modelService.find(myPartId, application);
    if (part == null) {
        part = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createPart();
        part.setLabel(ProcedureFlowChartPart.PART_TITLE);
        part.setContributionURI("bundleclass://MyPartPath");
        part.setElementId(myPartId);
        ((MWindow) window).getChildren().add(part);
    }
    partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
    window.setToBeRendered(true);
    modelService.bringToTop(window);
```